# What doesn't the disk size in the portal match what I see in my VM File Explorer?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

I spun up a new VM which gave me a 128GB OS disk. I expanded the size of that to 512GB, which can be seen below:

[image]

However, when I go into my VM, bring up File Explorer and look at my hard disk capacity, I still see the same original size:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start the VM from the portal and connect to the VM. Go to Disk Management, you will notice that the disk size has changed to 512 GB now. Right-click on the volume and select 'Extend Volume'. Follow the on-screen steps to extend the volume.

[image]

After that, you will see the expanded disk. Refresh, go back to C:\ to verify it. 
[image]